# Limit points of ${n+i+(-1)^n(n-i^n): n ∈ N}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, limits

What are the limit points of

$$ \{n+i+(-1)^n(n-i^n): n ∈ \Bbb N\}$$
as subset of $\Bbb C$

My guess is that there aren't any but I'm not sure about it

Comment: Hint: you can get a more descriptive version of this set by analyzing what happens for odd and even $n.$

Comment: My try was to create 4 subsets: a_4n a_4n+1 a_4n+2 a_4n+3

Comment: That should work. Maybe you can explain where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you study the powers of the imaginary number you would see that:
$$i^{4k}=1$$
$$i^{4k+1}=i$$
$$i^{4k+2}=-1$$
$$i^{4k+3}=-i$$
On the other hand:
$$2k+(-1)^{2k} 2k=4k$$
$$(2k+1)+(-1)^{2k+1}(2k+1)=0$$
If you expand the cases of the first part to the second:
$$(4k)+(-1)^{4k} 4k=8k$$
$$(4k+1)+(-1)^{4k+1} (4k+1)=0$$
$$(4k+2)+(-1)^{4k+2} (4k+2)=8k+4$$
$$(4k+3)+(-1)^{4k+3}(4k+3)=0$$
I think you should be able continue after this.